How to return app version on Jetpack Compose (IntelliJ IDEA Desktop)
On build.gradle.kts, i added the version of my code:
group:"br.com.example" 
version: "1.0.0"

However, i need to return it to my code, such as:
fun Main(){
title="Hello World Project v${version}}"

I want it to be set like this, on the output:
Hello World Project v.1.0.0

Ps.: This project is running for Desktop, so version.properties does not exist on the project path.

This question is similar to: Get Version in Kotlin/Java code in Gradle project. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

buildDir/resources/main/version.properties does not exist in Jetpack Compose for Desktop. Therefore, the example would not serve. I needed some way to return the version value within build.gradle.kts. It could be through a library.

https://github.com/yshrsmz/BuildKonfig
